# Tkinter, передача значения переменной

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть код:

```
def send_value(parameter, txt):
    parameter = txt.get()
    return parameter

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx import Document
from general_foos import choice_court
from general_foos import create_court
window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x250')
forming_ground_text(path2, path3, path)
document = DocxTemplate(path)
document2 = Document(path2)
applicant = " "
lbl = Label(window, text="Укажите истца:")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt1 = Entry(window, width=10)
txt1.grid(column=1, row=1)
btn = Button(window, text="Клик!", command=send_value(applicant, txt1))
btn.grid(column=2, row=1)
lbl2 = Label(window, text=applicant)
lbl2.grid(column=3, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Необходимо передать переменной applicant значение txt1.
Каким образом это можно сделать? Как нужно исправить код?

Comment: Вы хотите передать имя переменной именно через параметр функции? Напрямую не хотите записать?

Comment: Пробовал, через print проверяю, ничего не выдается, ни ошибки, ничего

Comment: Чтобы напрямую записать внутри функции надо там эту переменную объявить как `global applicant`.